# Unclear message after retagging a question

Tags: support, tags

After removing or adding a tag to a question the message at the top suggests that the submission will be executed only after another (??) condition is met. It reads:

```
Your edit will be placed in a queue until it is peer reviewed.
```

While the fact is: My 'edit' which is really only a retag is already in the queue. This is really confusing because at the bottom of the page there is a message suggesting that I have to do something else before the re-tag is accepted.

> Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:
>       You have the privilege to retag questions; to suggest an edit please include a change to the title and/or the body as well

So I go ahead any type in something like "bash tag not relevant here" and hit submit again. Same situation with the same messages at top and bottom. Out of frustration I try to submit three more times before I give up.

After trying to figure out what this thing really is, It turns out (I think) that the tag suggestion is in fact submitted even if it does not appear to be.

My real question is why do I get any messages at all if I am privileged to retag questions?

I see some tag is not right -  I'll change it. 
Site doesn't trust me and puts the re-tag through a queue? 
That's fine, what do I care? 
Just give me a green check mark after I click submit and I'll be off.

Am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To retag a question don't click on `edit` link. Click on `retag` link.

From [retag privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/retag-questions)

> **How do I retag a question?**
>
> Click the `retag` menu option under the post.

[image]

Comment: that seems intuitive enough :\

Comment: [Since recently](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177265/kill-the-retag-option-use-just-edit/179401#179401), the retag button no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

The [workflow for retagging has been improved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177265/kill-the-retag-option-use-just-edit/179401#179401): You can now do retags via the edit button.

For edits which only change tags, the edit will be immediately effective if you have the retag permission.