# Misleading banner when editing with the retag privilege but without the edit privilege

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, edits, suggested-edits

[The `retag` button is gone and only `edit` remains](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177265/kill-the-retag-option-use-just-edit/179401#179401). This has made a few negative changes for users with the retag privilege but not the edit privilege.

[image: Your edit will be placed in a queue until it is peer reviewed.]

The banner “Your edit will be placed in a queue until it is peer reviewed” is misleading, since in the case of a retag, for a user with the retag privilege, the edit is immediate and not reviewed.

I'm not sure what the right way forward is. Cluttering the banner with “Oh, except if you only retag” would be too much. But the information should be on the page somewhere.

Comment: hm, except that if user retags with retag privs, it is still peer reviewed. [Retags cause full edit procedure (Bug)](http://meta.superuser.com/q/6954) ex: http://superuser.com/posts/614744/revisions http://superuser.com/suggested-edits/31450 http://superuser.com/suggested-edits/31372

Comment: @Sathya That changed a couple of days ago, the [retag privilege was removed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182586/do-we-still-need-the-retag-privilege) and will be replaced by [something as yet undetermined](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186373/propose-a-privilege-to-sit-in-the-500-reputation-mark).

Comment: @Shog9 think it's better to prevent auto downvote in case of closing as off topic due to "can no longer be reproduced" - can't see much sense in that.

Comment: Yeah, Meta really hurts for the old "no longer relevant" close reason, @Sha.

Comment: @Gilles I was unaware of that; thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well I think it is important to explain your point to the user. Simply adding "Oh, except if you only retag" make it sound stupid indeed but I'm sure writing it in the bit of information at the bottom of the banner woudn't be a bad idea.

What about a different message for between 500 and 2000 reputation users ?

> Your edit will be placed in a queue until it is peer reviewed.
>
> We welcome all constructive edits, but please make them substantial. Avoid trivial, tiny one-letter edits unless absolutely necessary. Also, please note that retag edits are not submitted to a queue and are immediate.

Answer (score 1):

I think the message itself hints at the *proper* solution here. [As animuson wrote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177265/kill-the-retag-option-use-just-edit/179401#comment533208_177265) in the request that prompted this change,

> The only reason it existed was because users couldn't suggest edits once upon a time, and retagging was a legitimate privilege that let them edit the tags only.

The truth is, very few people even make use of the retag privilege anymore, and those who do are likely already used to suggesting edits... So the clean solution is to just get rid of this privilege entirely.

Comment: Admittedly it's not terribly important, but there's still the [issue of per-site metas](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179466/per-site-metas-no-longer-have-an-apparent-way-to-retag).

Comment: Yeah, please get rid of this 500 rep tagging privilege.