# Per-site metas no longer have an apparent way to retag

Tags: bug, tags, edits, suggested-edits, per-site-meta

[The `retag` button is gone and only `edit` remains](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177265/kill-the-retag-option-use-just-edit/179401#179401). This has made a few negative changes for users with the retag privilege but not the edit privilege.

On a child meta site (i.e. a meta site other than Meta Stack Overflow), the `edit` button is grayed out if you don't have the edit privilege, and there is no longer a `retag` button on questions. However, it is still [possible](https://reverseengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/198/revisions) to retag a question by manually visiting `http://meta.$sitename.stackexchange.com/posts/$id/edit`. It wouldn't be right to make that screen easily accessible though, as it looks like it allows editing the rest of the post.

(On a lark, after successfully retagging, I tried editing the body. This added an entry in my [activity](https://reverseengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/users/107/gilles?tab=activity), but as a revision that didn't make any change; the edit itself seems to have been discarded, as it should have been.)

The retag interface should be retained on meta sites, or something equivalent.

Comment: As I understand it, you just use the edit link; if you have the retag permission and only retagged (not touched the title or the body during editing) your edit goes through, otherwise your edit is put into the edit queue. *Everyone* gets to see the edit link unless edit banned or there is a pending edit on the post.

Comment: @MartijnPieters There is no edit link on meta. (Except MSO, MSO isn't a meta site.)

Comment: You mean per site meta, "meta" as a single word is used to refer to this site.

Comment: @Gilles: Right, that was not clear. I did not realize that per-site metas don't have an edit link, for example.

Comment: @MartijnPieters they have, but grayed out. Added that into the post.

Comment: By the way, without the edit privilege, if I visit the `/posts/$id/edit` page, I get the error “There is a pending suggested edit in the queue, try again in a few minutes.”. Which is not exactly correct, but close enough.

Comment: Wow, I just had the weirdest experience ever, visiting the questions tab. 3 questions of yours with the exact same first sentence...Trippy...

Comment: @Bart serial bug reporter? :-)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I flagged it as awesome

Comment: **Sorry. I guess I'm responsible for that.** :)

Comment: No longer relevant since the retag privilege has disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

The "something equivalent" in this case would be enabling suggested edits. [As I wrote here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179463/misleading-banner-when-editing-with-the-retag-privilege-but-without-the-edit-pri/179605#179605), suggested edits have pretty much made the "retag" privilege obsolete anyway.

That said, I'm still not convinced that *most* child metas have any need for either suggested edits or low-rep retags: there's just not that much traffic, and activity on the main site will garner you full editing privileges on the meta. For those rare occasions when you *do* need widespread collaborative editing, Community Wiki actually still serves a purpose.

Comment: Those metas where 80% of the questions are tagged [meta-tag:discussion] make my retag finger itch.

Comment: That's rarely the worst retagging sin on child metas, at least in my experience.