# Should I still be seeing an 'edit tags" link?

Tags: support, edits

According to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177265/kill-the-retag-option-use-just-edit/179401#179401), "retag" is dead (just use edit).  But I'm still seeing an "edit tags" link, on hover only, on both beta and graduated sites:

[image: link on mouse hover]

Should I be?

Comment: I bet the answer to this is.... caching.

Comment: A 6-week cache?  Wow. :-)

Comment: Actually, 6-8 weeks.

Comment: Ah, I thought 6-8 weeks was for *features*, not *everything*. :-)

Comment: Thats what they want you to think ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's a feature available with the [access to moderator tools](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools) privilege. It's simply there for the convenience of experienced users and moderators, and it's unrelated to the [retag](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/privileges/retag-questions) privilege which actually limits users to the ability to retag questions without being able to perform any other edits without being subjected to peer review.

Comment: But in the screenshot Monica only has rep of 7,434 so wouldn't have access to those tools.

Comment: I thought that you get the `retag` link when you hit 2k+ and can edit without review..

Comment: @JonW: That's Biblical Hermeneutics, where the rep requirement is listed as 2000 (I assume that's for beta sites in general).

Comment: The screen cap is from a beta site.  I also checked ELU but since I wasn't thinking about it being tied to rep, that was an unfortunate choice (10k).

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn yup