# "A Theory of Moderation" update

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, blog

The [Theory of Moderation](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/) blog post has some outdated information:

> [image]

Im pretty sure it is still a suggested edit at 500 reputation. (I tried it [C++ templates with derived classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824070/c-templates-with-derived-classes#19824070))

The privileges screen doesn't have it either, please update the blog post as well.

Comment: There used to be such privilege, it was [removed six months ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179401/152859). I suspect many blog posts are outdated, both text and screenshots, won't harm to update them to prevent confusing people.

Comment: I think it's quite reasonable for old blog posts to be outdated, *provided* they are not regularly referenced as containing definitive information. Do any official SE pages link to this blog post?

Comment: @Duncan yes: http://stackoverflow.com/review/ the *you* on the right is the reference

Comment: This is an exact duplicate question of [this deleted one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/197480/187824), where @Duncan said that people will forgive it since it is out of date. Also any moderator's page links to that blog.

Comment: @hims056 Ah, well I would retract my statement now that I know it's directly referenced as gospel by SE pages.

Comment: @hims056 too bad you asked to disassociate the question from your account, otherwise we could undelete and revive it! :)

Comment: @Duncan That particular blog post is also referenced on every election page. See, for example: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/election/1 (the link under "accorded the highest level of privilege on our community")