# Is the Retag Privilege still in effect?

Tags: support, privileges

Recently I [retagged a post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20954044/revisions) and was surprised to see it go into the review queue. I had expected it to just go through straight away and I also didn't expect to get reputation for it (as all I did was remove one tag and add another).

I am aware that the retag button was [merged with the edit functionality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177265/kill-the-retag-option-use-just-edit).

[Oded's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179401/188759) to the above question also suggests that the retag privilege does still exist.

But I do not see it [on the privilege list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges).

Where was a [discussion here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182586/do-we-still-need-the-retag-privilege/187324#187324) about if the priviledge was still nessasasry, which is marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) but there is no post from a staff memeber so it's unclear what exactly happened as a result of this dicussion.

So is the privilege in effect but missing from the list?

Comment: Have a look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186373/182868

Comment: There used to be such a privilege at 500 rep but it was removed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While there used to be a retag privilege at 500 rep; allowing retagging without approval, that privilege was removed due to confusion surrounding it; see [Do we still need the Retag privilege?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182586/do-we-still-need-the-retag-privilege) for more details.

The 500 rep privilege was ultimately changed for "Access to the First Posts and Late Answer Review", see [Propose a privilege to sit in the 500 reputation mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186373/propose-a-privilege-to-sit-in-the-500-reputation-mark)
 for more details.

You can see all current privileges [on this list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), if it is not on that list then it is not a current privilege.